# c++ overloading stream operator, parameters by reference and anonymous instances

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

If I have a POD with an overloaded stream operator:

```
struct Value{
...
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Value &val);
...
};
```

I can't use the stream operator with anonymous instances.
for example I can't do:

```
cout<<Value();
```

This gives me:

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘Value’)
```

On the other hand, I can pass the POD by value, but I would like to avoid the copy. Is there a way to both?

```
Value v1;
cout<<v1<<" "<<Value()<<endl;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the operator should not modify the right operand, it should take it by `const` reference:

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Value &val);
```

`const` references can bind to temporaries, so it will work (and that's how the standard library does it as well).

Comment: Thanks that works! Unfortunately I can't vote you up yet, since I'm a new user.